# Why is vscode on ubuntu searching for the python dist-packages directory in a user's venv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, python-venv

I'm running vscode release (1.69.2 dated 7/18/22) with the python extension on Ubuntu 20.04. When I try to run some code with the debugger I get an exception because it can't find *my_venv_dir/lib/python3.8/dist-packages*.

I've read a bit about Ubuntu's use of dist-packages and site-packages but I haven't found any information that suggests that there should be a dist-packages directory in my venv. There isn't one. When I run the code without the debugger I don't see the exception. When I run it in the debugger, the exception occurs before I hit a very early breakpoint. The exception seems to happen in startup code. So I don't know if there's a venv issue or a vscode/python-extension issue.

I created the virtual env using *python -m venv*

Here's the call stack:

```
islink (/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py:167)
_joinrealpath (/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py:425)
realpath (/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py:391)
_run_code (/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py:87)
_run_module_as_main (/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py:194)
```

Maybe this is more useful:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/my/venv/dir/lib/python3.8/dist-packages'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 167, in islink
    st = os.lstat(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 425, in _joinrealpath
    if not islink(newpath):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 391, in realpath
    path, ok = _joinrealpath(filename[:0], filename, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
```

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the sys.path:

```
(myvenv) host:~/dev/myprj$ python                                   
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux                                           
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys                                             
>>> print(sys.path)        
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/my/venv/dir/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>>
```

Comment: Can you post the full error traceback?

Comment: Please paste the complete error report and `launch.json`.

Comment: @SuperStormer I added the stack trace.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I added the launch.json file. I'm pretty new to vscode. How do I get to a complete error report?

Comment: The mentions of `/usr/lib/python3.8` in the call stack and traceback are, to me, indicative of VSCode ignoring (parts of) the v-env. The Python executable should be found in the v-env directory, in the `bin` subdirectory.

Comment: You created the v-env with `python -m venv`; but how did you tell VSCode to use the v-env?

Comment: @9769953 - First I set 'Python: Venv Path' to point to the directory where I store my venvs then I used 'Python: Select Interpreter' to select the python executable which was myvenv/bin/python3.

Comment: Whether it is effective to reinstall or update `Python` extension? I think this seems to be a bug. You can create an issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something was corrupted in the vscode configuration.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling vscode but noticed that when I started up again, vscode remembered where I left off.  When I deleted the ~/.config/Code directory the problem was fixed.

I suspect that the corruption happened when I updated to a newer release but I can't be sure.

Comment: This all fixed it for me. Remember to backup your vscode settings first somehow!

Comment: I run into the same issue, and deleting ~/.config/Code solves it, but I finally discovered that I checked the box "Raised Exception" in the breakpoint panel...

Comment: @etham's trick worked for me. But I do not understand why exactly. If anyone has an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely cause is that you checked the `Raised exceptions`
checkbox on the debug pane.

Some exceptions are being raised and silently caught as part of the normal flow, but this checkbox causes a breakpoint to be hit.

*(Source: @etham's comment under the other answer)*